# mysqldump command does not run in mysql shell

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am getting the following error when I try to dump a specific table of mysql database.

**Steps:**

- SSH'ed to a machine
- Moved into the mysql session
- Executed the following command

> mysql> mysqldump -urefill -p refill Refill >
>   Users/zainbutt/Documents/Refill.sql; ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump
>   -urefill -p refill Refill > Refill2.sql' at line 1

Comment: `mysqldump` is a separate program. You're trying to run it from within the mysql monitor as if it was a query.

Answer (score 2):

`mysqldump` is a program in its own right, not a query to be called from within `mysql`. You call it from a shell, not from a `mysql` prompt.

Comment: could you please list down the steps?

Comment: what steps? it's a SEPARATE PROGRAM.

Comment: then how should I be able to take a dump?

Comment: You do exactly what you have done, but skip the bit where you move into a mysql session.

Comment: then it gives me the following error
$ mysqldump -urefill -p refill Refill > Users/zainbutt/Documents/Refill.sql;
-bash: Users/zainbutt/Documents/Refill.sql: No such file or directory

Comment: I need to backup that dump on my local machine

Comment: and it says: bash: Users/zainbutt/Documents/Refill.sql: No such file or directory

Comment: `mysqldump` won't automatically send the dump to your machine. You need to give it a file name on the server to save it to, and then transfer it afterwards. I suggest just writing it to `dump.sql` or something and then using SCP to pick it up from your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
mysql> mysqldump -u refill -prefill Refill > Users/zainbutt/Documents/Refill.sql
```